# How to restore scroll position on components (not window) in Angular on navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angular

So I have a layout like this:

[image]

Basically

```
<navbar/>
<router-outlet/>
```

Where the router-outlet has overflow: scroll, so it's scrollable (not the whole window, only the outlet part).

I'm using a reuse strategy that would keep tabs in memory rather than reinitializing them on every navigation change and it correctly restores scroll position when I remove the overflow: scroll but that doesn't keep the navbar on the top, and when using that, whenever I click back or just click on the navbar to restore that component, it keeps scrolling back to the top.

Is there a way to keep the components from redrawing every time the user goes back to them or is there anyway to restore scroll position when only a part of the window is scrollable and not the whole thing?

Comment: I’m afraid you’d have to code something custom for that.. so keep scroll position in a service and restore on component load..

Comment: @MikeOne That's unfortunate.. Is this the same for all other frameworks such  as react and vue.js?

Comment: At least angular gives you scroll restore on the router included (so for the main router outlet, not for this scenario). I don’t think at least react gives you that out of the box. This issue is too specific to handle on framework level anyway.

Comment: However, this can be fairly easily solved with some custom code.. not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to particular div or any area in angular refer this code
here href name and id name should be same.

```
<div>
  <a href="#para">scroll</a>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="para">iam here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).